# Draggable elements hang in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got a bug from testers when they double clicked on element or something like then dragged it to the bottom of page,even if draggable element has containment set,mouse goes down than the element. After that you can release mouse click and draggable element hang on mouse pointer. Only in IE :( has anyone any ideea why or how to stop this?

My code looks like :

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/j2GyK/

```
function dragNdrop(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       dragObjects.push(document.getElementById("box" + i));

    $(dragObjects[i]).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
    $(dragObjects[i]).draggable({       
            containment:'#decor',
            zIndex: 1000,
            revert: true,

            start: function(event, ui) {
                dragTarget = event.currentTarget; // luam date despre obiectul curent tras
            } 
        });    
    }

        $("#drop").droppable({
         drop: function( event, ui )
            {
                    dropTarget = event.target; // luam date despre drop target
                    $(dropTarget).prop('src', dragTarget.src);
                    $(dragObjects).css("visibility", "visible");
                    $(dragTarget).css("visibility", "hidden");
                    thisSRC = dropTarget.src.charAt(dropTarget.src.length-5);
                    checkBtn.disabled = false; 
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle example of it?

Comment: What IE version are you using?